# Multiple event types in same Kafka Topic - consumer perspective

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

There are several posts on how to emit multiple events on same Kafka topic based on article https://www.confluent.io/blog/multiple-event-types-in-the-same-kafka-topic/.

My question is how does it work from consumer point of view? How can the access be controlled to provide fine grained access based on consumer role. eg. if we write both customer demographics and address on same topic but want to give access to only address topic for a consumer, how to go about it?

Has anyone worked from consumer end? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for a Kafka consumer to subscribe to only part of a partition (ignoring things like seeking to an offset, this not consuming messages before that offset, etc.): if you're subscribed, you're getting everything.

However, a consumer is free to ignore messages it's not interested in.

So something as simple as reading every message and then an `if` to branch to handling the message or doing nothing but committing the offset will work.

Note that if your consumption approach deserializes every message before presenting it to you, this implies that you'll need to be able to deserialize every message.  It may be necessary for the consumer to treat messages from Kafka as byte arrays or strings and perform further deserialization outside of Kafka: this does entail a risk of dropped messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give access to only a type of event in a topic. If a consumer can subscribe to a topic, it will get every event of that topic.

If you need to restrict access to some types of events, I suggest you to group those "secured" types of events in topics based on the role needed to access them.

Another approach would be to make the producer encrypt the content of those events and share its public key with only authorized consumers. But that would add some overhead on the system and prevent the use of Avro schema.